# How can I get summary information from images?

Tags: delphi, winapi, image

How can I get the summary information for file images in Delphi?

Comment: What information are you after width, height, etc?

Comment: Yes. All the items that you can see in the image file Properties/summary - Image

Answer (score 6):

You will have to use parsers for each file type.  The simple solution would be to use something like [GraphicEx](http://www.soft-gems.net/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=13&Itemid=33) and to load each supported image into a temporary object, extract the information you want then dispose of it.

For EXIF information (the information attached by modern day cameras) you might want to use a different component.  I know there are a few components floating around that will give you access to this special format, however this data is not supported by all image types and is normally seen in JPEG files.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need anything.

It's included in Windows (Win32 COM)

See on [Win32 api group](http://news://nntp.aioe.org/comp.os.ms-windows.programmer.win32)  (classic question...)